# Internet connection unavailable message for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an application that needs to load its data from the server when it first launch, i want to add a message that alert user in case the internet connection is not active as it is done right now it crashes when there's no connection. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If its related to failing internet connection you can use one of the NSURLConnectionDataDelegate methods:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

UIAlertView*aview=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Connection Failed" message:@"Please check your internet connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil ];
[aview show];
[aview release]; // Notify the user about the failure.

NSLog(@"Reason:%@",[error description]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Reachability class to check network connection
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html